# ApacheDS and PHP LDAP SSL Binding: Certificate Issue

Tags: php, apache, ssl, ldap, apacheds

The ApacheDS generates a certificate (X.509v1) upon authentication. (As far as I understand)
How would I handle this with a PHP ldap_connect?
Do I need to install the ApacheDS certificate somewhere?

Using an app like LDAPAdmin authenticates fine, however there is a certificate prompt.
I have no idea how to handle this in PHP.
I tried to use Apache Directory Studio to see if I could download a certificate somewhere to no avail. (To somehow setup Apache with it: $dir/newcerts -> openssl.cnf)

I also tried connecting to the url directly with the correct port, it downloads a file containing the message: PROTOCOL_ERROR: The server will disconnect

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create the following directory: C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf adding a file named ldap.conf containing the text TLS_REQCERT never